# Modify value const method

Tags: c++

why i can modify this string value ?
I0st const method , but the working is 
irrational for me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo : private std::string
{
public:
    Foo(const char* c) :std::string(c) {}
    const std::string& name() const
    {
        (std::string&)(*this) = "Change";
        return (const std::string&)(*this);
    }
};
int main()
{
Foo temp("value1");
std::cout << temp.name();
}
```

This will output

```
Change
```

Comment: C casts like `(std::string&)` tell the type safety system (including const correctness) to take a break. You give up on the compiler helping you by telling you about your mistakes. `static_cast<std::string&>(*this) = "Change";` will work if `name()` isn't `const` and will properly complain if `name()` is left `const`.

Comment: The code shown has compilation errors. `Class` should be `class` and `temp::` doesn't seem like it belongs there at all. If you fix those errors, you have undefined behavior and it *might* output `Change` but it can do anything.

Comment: "This will output

Change" - No. It *may* output that. It may also output nothing or it may output "Hello world" or it may crash. The code has [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and you get no guarantee what-so-ever about what it will do. It's just broken code, plain and simple.

Comment: Sorry i corrected the code, now its work

Comment: "now its work" - No it doesn't. It may *compile*, but that's a far cry from "working". Just because something compiles does *Not* mean that it is valid C++ - not even close. And this code is *not* valid. It has Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: *"I shot my foot right off, and the compiler didn't do anything about it, why?"* That the major thing about C++, it doesn't prevent you from doing bad things.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not completely sure, but I don't think this is UB, since OP doesn't call `name()` on an actual `const` object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's a good point. I guess I should have said "bad style" and "UB if the object the function is invoked on is declared `const`".

Comment: The code says "pretend that the type of this object is `std::string&`", and the compiler says "okay". Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C style explicit cast like `(std::string&)(*this)` can cast almost anything to everything else, with no regard as to whether or not you are allowed to use the result. An explicit cast is also usually interpreted by the compiler as telling it *"I know what I am doing."*, so there won't be any warnings if you misuse explicit casts.

In particular the C style explicit cast first tries to do

```
const_cast<std::string&>(*this);
```

which is impossible, because a `const_cast` can only add or remove `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, but can not change the type otherwise.

Then it tries

```
static_cast<std::string&>(*this);
```

which is is not possible, because `static_cast` can not remove a `const` qualification, but `*this` is `const`-qualified in the function.

Then it tries a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, e.g. equivalent to

```
const_cast<std::string&>(static_cast<const std::string&>(*this));
```

This succeeds because `*this` is derived from `std::string` and can be bound to a `const std::string&` reference. The `const_cast` then removes the `const` qualifier.

The result will be a reference to the `std::string` base class subobject.

You can in principle use this reference and assign to it as you are doing in your code. If however the complete object itself that `this` refers to is declared as `const`, e.g. if in `main` you have

```
const Foo temp("value1");
```

instead, then your code will *still compile without warning*, but it will have *undefined behavior*, because modifying a `const` object is undefined behavior, even if you were able to obtain a non-`const` reference or pointer to it.

This is why using `const_cast` is in most cases bad style and if it is used at all, special care needs to be taken, that the object it refers to can never be declared `const`. You are not taking that care in your code.

The C style explicit cast can (in addition to many other dangerous casts) do a `const_cast` and should for the same reason (and others) not be used.

What you really want here is a `static_cast` that will only cast references and pointers in the class hierarchy and will not violate `const`-correctness:

```
static_cast<std::string&>(*this) = "Change";
```

This will give you the appropriate error message if the member function is `const`-qualified and will work without undefined behavior otherwise.

Or, as long as you don't overwrite the `operator=` overload in the derived class, you can call the base class `operator=` also simply without cast. That will also give an appropriate error if the member function is `const`-qualified and will work without undefined behavior otherwise:

```
*this = "Change";
```